# Xcode: hide / protect resource files in final iOS app?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, encryption

I plan to develop an app for iOS and want to use HTML5, CSS and Javascript. The final app should be implemented as a native app using Xcode and `UIWebView`.

Can I hide or protect my html files in the final app? I have to put the files in the folder called **"Supporting Files"** in Xcode. Therefore, everyone can view the plain files after purchasing the app by extracting the .ipa file, right?

Answer (score 9):

There's many ways to protect your data, depending on how good you want the protection to be.  For very minimal protection against only casual hackers, you could use a string **obfuscation** algorithm to obfuscate and de-obfuscate the HTML content as `NSString`s.  Here's an [example of doing that](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/cocoa/obfuscation-encryption-of-string-nsstring.html).  I haven't used that particular code, but I'm also not really recommending *obfuscation* as a technique, unless the data really isn't very sensitive.

The better solution is to **encrypt** the HTML content, although that's more work, and may involve some [export control issues](http://www.bis.doc.gov/licensing/do_i_needaneccn.html), depending on where you are, and where you're distributing your app.

For encryption, you have lots of options.

**1)** [Here is an open source implementation that provides a secure version of something like `NSUserDefaults`](http://maniacdev.com/2011/08/open-source-ios-keychain-wrapper-for-easily-securing-user-data-for-your-app/).  I don't see an equivalent to `registerDefaults:` in that code, though, so it's possible that the **first** time your app runs, you may have to download the content from the web.  But, then you could encrypt and store it in `PDKeychainBindings` as a string value.  On subsequent runs, you could then extract stored HTML *"files"* like this:

```objc
NSString* webPageContent = 
    [[PDKeychainBindings sharedKeychainBindings] valueForKey: @"index.html"];
```

**2)** Here's another [open source project that provides AES encryption wrappers](https://github.com/rnapier/RNCryptor).  You would write some non-production code before releasing your app to encrypt the HTML content into encrypted data files that would be bundle resources.  When your app runs, it opens the files and decrypts them into `NSString` objects which can be given to your `UIWebView` via `loadHTMLString: baseURL:`.

**3)** Finally, [here's another example of using the underlying **CommonCrypto** APIs to protect bundle resources](http://aptogo.co.uk/2010/07/protecting-resources/).  This example uses a custom build step to automatically encrypt resources in a particular folder, which would save you some time if your protected HTML content is going to change reasonably often.

Answer (score 1):

You can encrypt the files and decrypt them at runtime or you can not include them in your bundle and have a compile time script that reads them and converts them into encoded data in your app that you can just load into your UIWebView with:

```
- (void)loadData:(NSData *)data MIMEType:(NSString *)MIMEType textEncodingName:(NSString *)encodingName baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL
```

Comment: I'm assuming you mean "encrypt" and "decrypt" in the first sentence, right?

Answer (score -4):

You could create all your HTML and so on also within your code and then use `UIWebView`'s

```
- (void)loadHTMLString:(NSString *)string baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL
```

to manually load every HTML string as plain text. I advice you, however, not to do so. If somebody really wants to isolate every string from your compiled source code, this is possible for him (unless you really do demanding stuff).

Most of the users simply don't care about what's inside the ipa file. If you can live with < 1% who inspects it, don't worry too much about this topic.

Another aspect would be possible as well (even if this is not a fantastic idea): You could point your UIWebView to a secret website only you and your app know. This is **absolutely not advisable**.